# Mean for specific lat lon coords using Python Xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, average, python-xarray

I would like to compute mean of specific lon lat points using Xarray: (-41.25, -3.75), (-38.75, -6.25) and (-38.75, -3.75). It is a simple idea, to get the values ​​of points and compute the mean.

I read that the *xarray.DataArray.sel_points* function has been discontinued and I have no idea how to calculate using only *xarray.DataArray.sel*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following DataArray:

```
>>> da
<xarray.DataArray (time: 5, lon: 4, lat: 3)>
array([[[...]]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2 3
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2
```

And you want to select the following (lon, lat) points :

```
>>> points = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 1)]  # list(tuple(lon, lat), ...)
```

Then, you're not sticking to the original (lon, lat) grid, so you can stack those dimensions together:

```
>>> da.stack(pos=("lon", "lat"))
<xarray.DataArray (time: 5, pos: 12)>
array([[...]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * pos      (pos) MultiIndex
  - lon      (pos) int64 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
  - lat      (pos) int64 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
```

From there, you can select the points:

```
>>> da.stack(pos=("lon", "lat")).sel(pos=points)
<xarray.DataArray (time: 5, pos: 3)>
array([[...]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * pos      (pos) MultiIndex
  - lon      (pos) int64 0 0 2
  - lat      (pos) int64 0 1 1
```

Compute their mean accross time:

```
>>> da.stack(pos=("lon", "lat")).sel(pos=points).mean("time")
<xarray.DataArray (pos: 3)>
array([24., 25., 31.])
Coordinates:
  * pos      (pos) MultiIndex
  - lon      (pos) int64 0 0 2
  - lat      (pos) int64 0 1 1
```

And, if required, come back to the original grid by unstacking:

```
>>> da.stack(pos=("lon", "lat")).sel(pos=points).mean("time").unstack("pos")
<xarray.DataArray (lon: 2, lat: 2)>
array([[24., 25.],
       [nan, 31.]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 2
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1
```

Note that there will be `nan` values where points of the new grid were not selected (that's why we stacked first).

Comment: For spatial mean: da.stack(pos=('lon', 'lat')).sel(pos=points).mean('pos')